# What does dijit.registry.remove() do?

Tags: dojo

What does dijit.registry.remove() do?  How does it handle invalid parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dijit.registry` reference is an instance of `dijit.WidgetSet`, which is a collection of widgets.

The `remove()` function accepts an input ID and removes that Widget with the corresponding ID from the collection, if found.

In Dojo 1.4, `WidgetSet` is defined within **dijit/_base/manager.js**.

The passed ID is used internally as the key looked in an associative array.  It's used like: this._hash[id], so passing it garbage will result in nothing being found or removed.